# I have a text with html and css and need formatted text

Tags: html

I am re-making a website that takes tests. It was on PHP and now we are taking it to TypeScript.
I am using React and Material UI to display the feedback for the correct answer and explanation when the user sends their answer.

I get the feedback from an old database they were using (and that we will still use), and what they used to do was create a variable called html (string), and then concatenate each part of the html code raw.
Something like this: (in PHP .= and . is what you use to concatenate)

```
$html = '';
$html = '<div>';
$html .= '<p class="maintext"><span>' . $some_variable_they_want_in_span . '</span>';
$html .= $some_other_variable_that_is_empty_or_not_depending_on_if_clause . '</p>';
$html .= '</div>';
```

it is a pain... but the thing is. Now that I am showing the feedback, it comes in a terrible format that I can't simply show in a Typography element (Material UI, but I couldn't in a -p- tag either).

The text is, for example, this one:

```
" &lt;p&gt;Artículo séptimo.\n&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;1. En el ejercicio de sus funciones, los miembros de las Fuerzas y Cuerpos de Seguridad tendrán a todos los efectos legales el carácter de AGENTES DE LA AUTORIDAD.\n&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;2. Cuando se cometa delito de atentado, empleando en su ejecución armas de fuego, explosivos u otros medios de agresión de análoga peligrosidad, que puedan poner en peligro grave la integridad física de los miembros de las Fuerzas y Cuerpos de Seguridad, tendrán al efecto de su protección penal LA CONSIDERACIÓN DE AUTORIDAD.\n&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;3. La Guardia Civil sólo tendrá consideración de fuerza armada en el cumplimiento de las misiones de carácter militar que se le encomienden, de acuerdo CON EL ORDENAMIENTO JURÍDICO.\n&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;\n&lt;/p&gt; "
```

How can I show this in a readable and nice text? I tried some npm packages and passing it through decodeURI but no change. Any ideas? Some text will even come with something like

```
"Artículo 2. Secretaría de Estado de Seguridad.&lt;div&gt;Corresponde a la persona titular de la Secretaría de Estado de Seguridad el ejercicio de las funciones a las que se refiere el artículo 62 de la Ley 40/2015, de 1 de octubre, y en particular, la dirección, coordinación y supervisión de los órganos directivos dependientes de la Secretaría de Estado, bajo la inmediata autoridad de la persona titular del Ministerio, para el ejercicio de las siguientes funciones:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style=\&quot;letter-spacing: -0.015rem;\&quot;&gt;El ejercicio del mando de las Fuerzas y Cuerpos de Seguridad DEL ESTADO, y la COORDINACIÓN Y SUPERVISIÓN DE LOS SERVICIOS Y MISIONES QUE LES CORRESPONDEN.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;"
```

Comment: The last line should be `$html .= '</div>';`. You forgot it is `.=` for the last line as well.

Comment: Yeah, thanks... Anyway that's just an example of the old way so you can get an idea of how things were done, but that's not part of the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So one of my coworkers found this solution:

import textParserTest from "~/utils/textparser"; // (which uses in its code the following: import parse from "html-react-parser";)
...

```
          <div
            contentEditable="true"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: textParserTest(props.question.answer, 0)
                .toString()
                .replaceAll("\\n", ""),
            }}
          ></div>
```

So basically. html-react-parser package did the trick